# Internet Explorer 9 - Resize image proportionally

Tags: css, image, resize

I'm trying to limit image width with CSS only:

```
#lateral-derecho #patrocinadores img
{
    max-width: 130px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And every browser is doing it all right except IE 9. It's not doing it proportionally. I'm running it in `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`.

BTW, IE 9 in standards mode does not even understand `margin: 0 auto;` or I'm doing something wrong? they did a crappy browser again?

Edit: this is all the CSS, container (#patrocinadores) and img, img is contained inside `#patrocinadores > a > img`:

```
#lateral-derecho #patrocinadores
{
    float: right;
    width: 136px; 
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 15px 0 5px;
    background: url(images/top-patrocinadores.png) top no-repeat #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

#lateral-derecho #patrocinadores a{display: block;}
#lateral-derecho #patrocinadores img
{
    max-width: 130px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#lateral-derecho #patrocinadores a {
    display: block;
    max-width: 130px;
}
#lateral-derecho #patrocinadores img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you want good quality scaling for IE < 9, you'll want to include the `AlphaImageLoader` and set `sizingMethod` to `scale`.

Comment: Thank you, but doesnt't work also... Are you all sure IE9 doesn't do this in your machines? IE8 works properly, but IE9 doesn´t...

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `height: auto;`. You don't need it, and it's the cause of the problems.

Comment: No, actually, if I get rid of it, all browsers resize it not proportionally, also IE9, so I need it for the real browsers to work. Thanks

Comment: @user761076 No, then you have some incorrect css somewhere else. Why would other browsers set the hight if you don't tell them to? No. Somewhere you are setting a height on this image, and you should not be. Use firebug to figure out where and remove it as well.

Comment: @user761076 Hmm - are you including the height in the image tag? If you are then remove it (and the width as well). Don't set dimension both in the tag and in css, it causes strange problems.

Comment: No, there's no height in image tag, and no height in any container